# Java Applet PDF printing

Tags: java, pdf, applet

I am trying to build a java applet which prints a PDF file and sends it to a label printer rather than the default. I explored desktop.print but couldn't work out how to specify the printer.

This is the code I have, i've tried to look for solutions but have ended stuck. I have signed the applet and the error it gives me it just says application error 0

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.print.*;
import javax.print.*;  
import javax.print.attribute.*;   
import javax.print.attribute.standard.*; 


public class printPDF extends JApplet {

    public void init(){ 
            String uri = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\jobbase\\print.pdf"; 

            DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.PDF;


            PrintRequestAttributeSet aset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
            aset.add(new PrinterName("label", null));
            aset.add(new Copies(1));


            PrintService[] pservices =
                    PrintServiceLookup.lookupPrintServices(flavor, aset);

            if (pservices.length > 0) {

                    DocPrintJob printJob = pservices[0].createPrintJob();

                    try{
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(uri);
                        Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(fis, flavor, null);


                        try {
                            printJob.print(doc, aset);
                        } catch (PrintException e) { 
                            System.err.println(e);
                        }

                        } catch(IOException ioe){
                            ioe.printStackTrace(System.out);
                    }
            } else {
                    System.err.println("No suitable printers");
            }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just send the PDF to the printer unless you know it can understand it. Most of the time you need to rasterize it on the client. I write a blog article explaining the options at http://www.jpedal.org/PDFblog/2010/01/printing-pdf-files-from-java/

Answer (score -1):

If you know the name of the printer you can achieve this. In one client I needed silent printing: if a printer named `appprinter` was present, I used it, if not I tried with the default. This worked out fine.

For printing I use [ICEPDF](http://www.icesoft.org/java/projects/ICEpdf/overview.jsf).

Kate: thanks for the suggestion, honestly IcePDF is pretty straight forward, this example is included in the source code that you can download from the link above. In order to obtain the PrinterService (aka printer) needed you can delete all the user input requested by keyboard and just use the one with the name you want.

So, in version 5.0.5: [install-folder]/examples/printservices/PrintService.java

1. delete user selection of printservice: lines 106 to 155
2. add instead:

   ```
   PrintService selectedService=null;
   for (int j=0;j<services.length;j++) {
       if ("myprintername".equalsIgnoreCase(services[j].getName())) {
           selectedService=aux[j];
       }
   }
   ```

Hope now it is more useful.

Best regards.

Comment: Show the code to make this a useful answer. As it stands you're saying it can be done, but not showing how.